add Google Chat to an invite
As soon as an appointment is created in the calendar, a chat is automatically created with the people invited. For example: 10 minutes before the start, the chat appears in Google Chat on the left-hand side.
I would like this to be included in the following script.

function invite() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let events = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("events").getValues();
  let alreadyCreated = [];
  let newEvents = []

  events.forEach(function(e){
    if(e[14]){
      alreadyCreated.push(e[27])
    }else{
      newEvents.unshift(e[27])
    }
  });
  
  events.forEach(function(e, index){
    let calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("myID");
    if(!e[14]){
      calendar.createEvent(
        e[27],
        new Date(e[19]),
        new Date(e[20]),
        {description: e[26],guests: e[17],sendInvites: true}
      );
      let newIndex = index+6
      sheet.getRange("P"+ newIndex).setValue('true')

    }
  })

  
}

function getid(){
  let calendarIDFromCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("id").getValue();
  Logger.log(calendarIDFromCell)
}



Welcome to Stack Overflow. See Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question and How do I ask a good question?
